# How to view Environment texture in Solid / Texture / Material view?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, shaders, hdri

I saw this happening in some tutorial, but have forgotten for the moment,
What I want is : **To make the HDR environment texture appear in 3D viewport without going into Render Mode**. I can use the following :

1. Material Mode
2. Texture Mode
3. Solid Mode

Actually, there is **some Setting** (i suppose)
through which this is achieved. Object textures are available but Environment texture is hidden in these 3 modes, and the **Reason behind this question** is that I dont want to burn my CPU, just in order to switch b/w modes to see the OBJECTs & HDR that they fit well or Not
[image: What I want]

Comment: I suggest selecting objects you'd like to preview with reflections and go into Local View (Numpad /) and then hit preview rendering; it really won't render long but you will see the result you're after. If you're just checking objects' shading then use Matcaps, they can visualize problems on mesh.

Comment: I just needed positioning of objects , that's why i have to switch b/w the modes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the <kbd>N</kbd> panel of the **3D View**, check *World Background* under *Display*.

[image]

**Note:** This won't change the shading of the objects, like if it were actually rendered, but just show you what the texture looks like.

Comment: Well,
that's the problem of the Blender version 2.71 which I am using

Comment: how to do this for blender 2.8+? I don't see any Display tab in the N panel?

Comment: @DerekEden for Blender 2.91.0 see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/208917