# How to view hdri in viewport "SOLID" mode?

Tags: 3d-view, hdri

I'm using Blender version 2.82.

The HDRI is visible in the render mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it is not possible someone tell me please , cause i searched about 2.7 and that was possible in 2.7

Comment: That's not possible as far as I'm aware. The environment texture is only shown in *Material Preview* and *Rendered* mode.

Comment: It was possible in older versions :| https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHisRVyczgE

Comment: The question is why? What exactly are you trying to accomplis? Solid mode is a simplified representation, independent of the scene lighting for a good reason: so that you can evaluate the shapes correctly without having to compute complex lights and textures. Are you trying to use a background image to assist you with the modeling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blender 2.91.0 I see the so called `Material Preview` mode which allows what you're looking for.

[image: Material Preview mode]

There I have the option to use the built in HDRI's or installing my own one by conveniently using the little gear icon on that pop-up window.

[image: HDRI setup]